# Should it be "it's our birthday today" or "it's our birthdays today"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

If two people were born on the same day, does one say to the other "it's our birthday today" or "it's our birthdays today"?

If they were born on different days, does one say to the other "we should meet on our birthday" or "we should meet on our birthdays"?

Comment: Your birthday is the anniversary of your birth. When you say 'born on different days' I assume you mean on the same date in different years? The anniversary is one day so it's 'our birthday'.

Comment: As Kate said the anniversary is one day so it's *our birthday*. From the opposite perspective, though, we might say *our birthdays are on the same day.*

If they're born on different days, one says to the other *we should meet on our birthdays*.

I don't understand why the Question belongs here at Users, rather than English Language Learners.

Comment: If two people were born on the same day then they share that single day as their birthday.

Answer (score 1):

Born on the same day: "It's our birthday today."

Born on different days: "We should meet on our birthdays."

The reason is that, in the first case, there is just *one* day. Therefore, birthday should be singular. In the second case, it should be plural because there are two day**s** (say, June 3 and October 7). Hence, birthday**s**.